# Как сделать статичный текст?

Tags: python, tkinter

Работаю с модулем tkinter, возник вопрос, не могу понять, как сделать статичный текст. Искал ответ на вопрос, так и до сих пор не нашёл. Вот код:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x100')
root.title('Завершение программы')
root.iconbitmap(r'cancel.ico')

text = Text(width=50, height=10)
text.pack()
text.insert(1.0, "Завершние программы через 3 секунды..")

text.tag_add('title', 1.0, '1.end')
text.tag_config('title', font=("Verdana", 10, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)
```

Текст не выводит. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Что значит "статичный текст"?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в моём понимает, это чтобы он был просто, как текст, чтобы его нельзя было изменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
label=Label(root,text=" 'Static' text")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```